# Distance involving 3D lines and vectors.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In this problem, **a** = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} and **b** = \begin{pmatrix} -11 \\ 1 \\ 28 \end{pmatrix}

Vectors **p** and **d** exist such that the line containing **a** and **b** can be expressed in form
**v** = **p** + **d**$t$.
Additionally, for a specific value of **d**, it is the case that for all points **v** lying on the same side of **a** that **b** lies on, the distance between **v** and **a** is $t$. What is the value of **d**?

Another problem I have no clue on as to how to solve, let alone begin. What should my "first step" be? Clarification on the last paragraph of the problem and hints are appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining points "on the same side of **a**"? Consider drawing a figure because it's hard to understand your description of the problem.

Comment: @dpmcmlxxvi; a point bisects a line

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello: I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean. Can you further clarify (if possible)?

Comment: i was answering a deleted comment so, mine probably makes no sense at all now

Answer (score 1):

$
\renewcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\vo}{\mathbf{v_0}}
\renewcommand{\p}{\mathbf{p}}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathbf{d}}
\renewcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}
\renewcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}
$
First, WLOG assume $\p = \a$, so that $\v = \p + \d t = \a + \d t$. 
Then  the distance between $\v $ and $\a$ is 
$$
\|\v - \a\| = \|\p + \d t - \a\|  = \|\a + \d t - \a\| = \|\d \| t
$$
Since we want to make sure that $\|\v - \a\| =  t$, we need to choose $\d$ such that 1) $\p$ is collinear with $\b-\a$, and 2) $\|\p\| = 1$. 
The most obvious choice is $\d = \dfrac{\b - \a}{\|\b - \a\|}$. 
Then we have 
$$
\|\v - \a\| = \|\a + \d t - \a\|  = \| \d \| t = 
\left\| \dfrac{\b - \a}{\|\b - \a\|}\right\| t = 
\dfrac{\left\| \b - \a\right\|}{\|\b - \a\|} t = t
$$
Thus, for a vector 
$$\v = \p + \d t = \a + \dfrac{\b - \a}{\|\b - \a\|} t$$
we have 
$$
\|\v - \a \| = t
$$

Comment: $\|(x,y,z)\|=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, so $\|b-a\| = \sqrt{(-11 -5)^2 + (1 + 3)^2 + (28 + 4)^2} = \sqrt{1296} = 36$

Answer (score 1):

That sentence should read something like this:

> Additionally, for a specific value of **d**, it is the case that for all points **v** lying on the ray from **a** to **b**, the distance between **v** and **a** is $t$.

If you want something more long-winded and avoiding the concept *ray*:

> Additionally, for a specific value of **d**, it is the case that for all points **v** lying on the line containing **a** and **b** where **a** is not between **b** and **v**, the distance between **v** and **a** is $t$.

This can be done first by finding letting **p** be point **a** and **d** be **b**-**a**. Find the coordinates of **d**. Then divide that vector by its own length, giving you a new **d** that has length $1$. That will then be the **d** that you want.

Is that clear?

Comment: I believe I understand the majority. Why would we divide the vector **d** by its own length?

Comment: Without that you do not get "the distance between **v** and **a** is $t$." That happens only if the length of **d** is $1$, and you make that happen by dividing **d** by its length. @Vlad's answer shows that in detail. I emphasized giving detail on "clarification on the last paragraph of the problem and hints" while Vlad gave details on why those hints are valid. Both answers are good: I answered the question you actually asked. Is the detail on **d** now clear?

Comment: Hi Mr. Daulton, yes, it makes sense now. If the length of **d** is $1$, would the vector **d** = $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}?$

Comment: @Grace: No. That vector has length $1$ but so do many other vectors. In your example, the first **d=b-a** is $(-16,4,32)$, which has length $\sqrt{(-16)^2+4^2+32^2}=36$, so the final **d** is $\left(-\frac 49,\frac 19,\frac 89\right)$. That final **d** has length $1$ so it works.